why $\mathbb{R}(t)$ is an infinite extension of $\mathbb{R}?$
Example of infinite extension of $\mathbb{R}$?
Here is the answer I found
It is written that

The most commonly studied example would be $\mathbb{R}(t)$, where $t$ is a new variable. This is the field of rational functions (a polynomial over a polynomial) in $t$. This is an infinite extension of $\mathbb{R}$.

My thinking :$[\mathbb{R}(t):\mathbb{R}]=1$ or $ 2 $
My question :I am not getting why $\mathbb{R}(t)$ is  an infinite  extension of $\mathbb{R}?$

$t$ is not a real number, nor a complex number. It's a new symbol, aka intermediate.

@KaleBhodre I think $\mathbb{R}(t)$  is not the set of all polynomials. Then how is that possible?

@jasmine You are right, it is not the set (or rather, ring) of all polynomials. It does, however, contain the set of all polynomials (as a subring).

I think it would help if you know the axiomatic definition of polynomial ring. Then $\mathbb R(t)$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb R[t]$.

Because the inverses of linear functions $\big\{\frac{1}{t-r} : r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent.
Proof: Consider a finite sum $\sum \frac{a_i}{t-r_i} = 0$. The left-hand side goes to infinity as $t \to r_i$ (the other terms are bounded) but the right-hand side doesn't.
